# ModelMapper How to map DTO to Domain Model without overriding attributs

Tags: spring, dto, modelmapper

My question is simple but till yet i do not find how to do ?
given following classes

```
public class DTOStudent{
private id;
private name;
private address;
}


public class Student{
private id;
private name;
private address;
}
```

using `ModelMapper` i have to map Source: `DTOStudent` to Destination: `Student`
**but in same cases** without modifying `address` attribute in `Student` class.

i'm using using `modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);`

Answer (score 0):

Please trying [skipping properties](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#skipping-properties).

In Java 6/7

```
modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<DTOStudent, Student>() {
    skip().setAddress(null);
});
```

In Java 8

```
modelMapper.typeMap(DTOStudent.class, Student.class)
    .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.skip(Student::setAddress));
```